# How to add "padding" to custom TabView scrollable content in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, tabview

I'm creating a custom TabView and content of tabs is scrollable.

Default TabView behaviour gives us ability to scroll content "under" the TabView (like it's a `ZStack`) and when we reach the end last block is placed exactly above the TabView like it has an offset or something (see pic. 1)

[image: Default TabView behaviour]

In my implementation of a custom `TabView` I use `ZStack` to place TabBar above the content, but when we scroll to the end, obviously, last block does not have ability to scroll higher like on the picture 1 and stays under the TabBar (see pic.2)

[image: Custom TabView behaviour]

How can I add "padding" to the content to make it look like I showed on the first picture? I have attached my CustomTabView layout below.

```
var body: some View {
    ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
        content
            .ignoresSafeArea(edges: .bottom)
        
        ZStack(alignment: .top) {
            CustomTabView(tabs: tabs, selection: $selection)
                .padding(.horizontal, 8)
                .padding(.top, 8)
                .background(.ultraThinMaterial)
            
            Divider()
        }
    }
    .onPreferenceChange(CustomTabBarItemsPreferenceKey.self, perform: { value in
        self.tabs = value
    })
}
```

**UPDATE:**
I realised that I need to disable somehow the clipping for the `ScrollView` inside `content` and found a solution that doesn't work for me:

```
extension UIScrollView {
    override open var clipsToBounds: Bool {
        get { false }
        set {}
    }
}
```

But in next release of Xcode for ScrollView will be added method [`scrollClipDisabled()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/nowplayingview/4162798-scrollclipdisabled?changes=_7_____8)

Comment: Any reasons you can't just add padding to the bottom of `content`?

Comment: If I add padding to the content won't be scrolled under the TabView and blur effect won't appear. I can easily replace ZStack with VStack to achieve this behaviour, but I want to show like scroll view is placed under the TabBar, you can check behaviour by yourself using ultraThinMaterial or similar with TabView

Answer (score 0):

As of Xcode Version 15.0 beta 1 (15A5160n) this can be done as follows:

```swift
<#T##SomeScrollView#>
  .scrollClipDisabled()
  .safeAreaInset(edge: .bottom, spacing: 0) {
    <#T##SomeView#>
  }
  .clipShape(Rectangle())
```